# Kafka Confluent cloud ElasticsearchSink Connector: Mapping collision in index

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

I have Kafka running on confluent cloud where I can produce data with a Node.js client, data is sent as a string and I get following fields in confluent cloud.[image]

Then, I created a `ElasticsearchSink Connector` and connected it to elastic search cloud. If I don't create any mapping in elastic search, transfer of data is successful as excepted and the format is something like this.

```
"_source" : {
          "booked" : false,
          "phone_number" : "919191919191",
          "location" : {
            "lon" : 60.23,
            "lat" : 78.233
          }
        }
```

Now the problem is If I want to run any `geo queries` it won't allow me and give the following error:

```
"root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "query_shard_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to find geo_point field [location]",
        "index_uuid" : "C8Xxu9QlTMKN4Lk1LjpOmQ",
        "index" : "locations"
      }
```

Reason being dynamic mapping does not support geo_field. So now when I try to create a custom mapping for elastic search while creating an index as follow:

```
PUT /locations
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "phone_number": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "booked": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Then confluent connector fails and shows the following error:

```
There is a mapping collision in your index: Can't merge a non object mapping with an object mapping.
```

I have also tried `booked` as a `text` field but things does not seem to work. I haven't enforced any schema on Confluent cloud.
Here is few basic config from confluent cloud.
[image]

How can I enforce mapping so that I can run `geo queries` in Elastic Search?

**UPDATE:** This problem persists mainly because of the format of data which is being sent to Kafka

```
{
    "phone_number": "919191919191",
    "location": {
            "lat": 78.233,
            "lon": 60.23
    },
    "booked": false,
}

{
    "phone_number": "+919191919190",
    "location": " 78.233, 60.23",
    "booked": false,
}
```

Both the format fails to map to above defined mapping in `ElasticSearch` and `connector sink` shows following error:

```
Received Illegal Argument Exception from Elasticsearch: One of your fields' type does not match the mapped type in Elasticsearch
```

Comment: Are you trying to add geo mapping to already dynamically mapped field location?

Comment: No, first I created the index and then added the mapping, but it didn't work. And I have also tried to add geo fields to dynamically mapped field. But none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Confluent Cloud does a sneaky job in figuring things out related to schema and storing that discovery on its built-in Schema Registry. I am afraid that your mappings won't work because:

1. The connector is still trying to send previous stored data.
2. Previous stored data is still attached to the old schema.
3. Confluent Cloud didn't realize that the schema have evolved.

Try to reset your setup by creating a new environment in Confluent Cloud (which will force the creation of a new SR instance) or perhaps use a brand new Kafka topic. Either way start with fresh data. The connector always tries to be optimistic and make sure no data is lost but in the process this might be faulty because the schema have evolved.

Set the mapping on Elasticsearch before anything. Once you have done this, the connector will map to the correct schema. Also, for some reason it only worked when I used dynamic templates on the mapping for the Elasticsearch index.